# Check remote servers port

Tags: powershell, port

i need a code that will check the domain or IP port if it opens then i need to send me a notification

so i have net framework code :

```
New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("google.com", 80)
```

but now i don't know how pul parameter so if it true=conected then execute the code to send email if not the start-sleep 1800 for example...

```
$ChkPortFile = "New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("google.com", 80)"
If ($ChkPortFile.conected -eq $True) {
execute code for email send or use downloadstring to execute
}
Else {start-sleep 1800}
```

so can you help to create code

Answer (score 0):

The quoting in your code is wrong for the `$ChkPortFile` variable, but also you have a typo in `conected`. (that needs double 'n').

As for the part of sending an email message, there are so many examples to be found on using the PowerShell [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage) cmdlet that I will leave that for you to implement yourself.

```
$hostName = 'google.com'
$port     = 80

try {
    $ChkPortFile = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($hostName, $port)
}
catch {
    throw
}
if ($ChkPortFile) {
    If ($ChkPortFile.Connected ) {
        # send an email.
        # have a look at the Send-MailMessage cmdlet at
        # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage

        # for now, just show the connected status on screen
        Write-Host "Connected to $hostName on port $port" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Not connected" -ForegroundColor Red
        #Start-Sleep 1800
    }    
    # cleanup the TcpClient object when done
    $ChkPortFile.Dispose()
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks for reply... here is an error : Method invocation failed because [System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient] doesn't contain a method
 named 'Dispose'.  and it always tells that connected why? i have tried port 44 on my ip address, i dont have open 44 port

Comment: thanks for reply... here is an error : Method invocation failed because [System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient] doesn't contain a method named 'Dispose'. and it always tells that connected why? i have tried port 44 on my ip address, i dont have open 44 por

Comment: @Switch I've updated my answer and wrapped it inside a try..catch block. As for the [Dispose method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.dispose)

Comment: Now the output is failing when port is closed and it is not repeating command... plus steal is the error: Method invocation failed because [System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient] doesn't contain a method named 'Dispose'

Comment: @Switch As far as I can see, all .net versions expose a `Dispose()` method on the System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.. You could try `.Close()` instead. By the way, where in your question or code does it repeat???

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
test-netconnection google.com -port 80
```